What does Ramschland mean, more precisely?
It's been literally translated as "junk country", but in what contexts is it typically used, e.g. is it a synonym for "third-world" or "rust belt", or something like that?
I found an older occurrence where it seems to mean something like the latter.

Es ist die Zeit, da die Bremer beschimpft und beschuldigt werden, »die Griechen von der Weser« zu sein. Ein Ramschland, das Deutschland mitschleppe wie Europa den südosteuropäischen Pleitestaat. Schwer vorstellbar, dass einem Finanzsenator in solchen Tagen seine Arbeit Freude macht.

Is that the way it's typically used?

Actually, in the highest Google results, it is used in the very concrete context of credit ratings. Bonds with a bad rating could be idiomatically called "Ramsch" (english: "junk bonds"). So a country would be called (not very tastefully) a "Ramschland" if their government bonds were "Ramsch".

I don't see that used commonly at all, and I see that word here the first time. It seems to me as common as the English combination "junk country". It's a makeshift word creation which is common in German, and well understandable in its derogatory meaning.
As to the meaning, "Ramsch" in this context does not translate well to junk in the sense of trash, but more in the sense of cheap, low-quality (like the Sun glasses from a street vendor compared to the one from a optometrist), cheap stuff no-one really needs.

Ramsch is leftovers. Stuff no one wanted to buy for the regular price, and neither at a reasonable discount. It's stuff you find at a rummage sale.
Bremen is a Ramschland in the sense of Ramschniveau. That's countries with credit rating B or worse.
